# RAKUDO_RAKUAST=1 raku --target=ast is not yet available

Tags: raku, rakudo, rakudo-star

It has been almost a year since I saw Jonathan Worthington presenting the new RakuAST in the YouTube video *[A Raku API to Raku programs the journey so far](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5-gNKRw4gY?t=229)*  from TRC 2021. In the video, he showed that we could dump this new RakuAST using `RAKUDO_RAKUAST=1` like this:

```perl
RAKUDO_RAKUAST=1 raku --target=ast -e 'say [*] 1..10'
```

I'm using the lasted version of RakudoStar, and yet, the command above still dumps the old QAST tree.

What is happening here?

**Why doesn't it show the new RakuAST and how can I compile rakudo the right way so that it does?**

For the build, I use the instruction on this page https://rakudo.org/downloads/rakudo/source for Linux with a slight modification because the instructions are slightly outdated. This is what I do instead of what the page tells me to (It worked previously but not anymore):

```
sudo perl Configure.pl --backends=moar --gen-moar --gen-nqp
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to checkout and build the `rakuast` branch of Rakudo. The RakuAST work is still very much in progress, and has not landed in the main branch let.